# jQuery ajax .load() results in 500 error in Internet Explorer only

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

This problem has been posted in other questions, however none of the proposed solutions have solved my particular problem.

I have a site with the following `META` tags implemented:

```
<title>My Site Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Assets/Media/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="keywords" content="some, useless, keywords">
<meta name="description" content="Site description.">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

And I'm using the following code to load content (pages) into my `#App` `<div>`, which is the main content area:

```
var section = 'About';

$('#App').fadeTo(0,0).empty().load(
    'Views/' + section + '.php',
    { section_object_ID : section, category_object_ID : objectID },
    function(){
        $('#App').transition({ opacity: 1, duration: 333, easing: 'easeOutQuint');
    }        
);
```

So the above code simply uses jQuery's `.load()` function to load `About.php` into  my content area:`<div id="App"></div>`

And it works perfectly in all versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. But it returns a 500 error Internet Explorer 8,9,10, and 11.

There is certainly no `500 - Internal Server Error` given that it loads perfectly fine, except in IE.

Here's some caps of the network traffic:

**Request**
[image]

**Response Headers**
[image]

**Response Body**
[image]

Anyone have any idea what this Microsoft piece of crap is doing wrong and how I could waste some more of my precious time fixing their mistakes to make the damn site load?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Just compare the headers sent by IE with other browser. 500 is a server-side error, not related to jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Hi @Cheery, I understand your thinking, but this is certainly *not* a true `500 Internal Server Error`, that's the response code I'm getting *only* when using IE. All other browsers work just fine and return a `200` code, with all the other request headers exactly the same. So, something's happening between me firing the `.load()` function and IE sending the `POST` request to my server. This is an IE bug, because Microsoft sucks at making software.

Comment: Again, it happens due to the config of your server or server-side script. Something, may be, sent not in the format your server expects, but mostly it is a problem of the server-side script or configuration of the server, as I said. Compare http requests from IE and other browser, check the difference. Check your server for that behavior. jQuery makes a simple http request, which in no way should lead to 500 error message.

Comment: Hi Cheery, I get it. But you're not following: this code works perfectly fine in all other browsers, therefore the root of the problem is how IE is sending the requests. However, the request headers for IE are exactly the same as all other browsers. Thus making it very difficult to debug the problem.

Comment: NO! the problem is that your script reacts differently on some data. The config of the server may 'react' differently even on the User-Agent string or on Referer data submitted. It may happen even if something wrong is stored in the PHP session - clear cookies in IE. But, for the third time, the problem is not here - it is on server's side. Probably with your FAQ.php script.

Comment: Wrong again. Why do you insist that it's a problem with my server-side script when I'm telling you that **ALL OTHER BROWSERS WORK PERFECTLY FINE**. The problem is IE-centric, and I'm not 'reacting', as you say, to any of the request headers. The server side script simply reads the `Request Body` from the PHP `$_POST` array. It's not a server side problem.

Comment: Nothing else can create a 500 error, which is a server-side error. The problem with the script or server's config. Check server's error logs. I'm not going to discuss it anymore, do whatever you want if you do not trust people with experience. Good luck.

Comment: Man, Cheery, you're just not understanding. I'm fully aware of how `500 Errors` are born. What I'm trying to tell you is that there's no good reason for the server to return a `500` given that it returns a `200` for **EVERY OTHER BROWSER**. So while the 500 may come into existence because of a bad request, it is `Internet Explorer` that is composing and sending that request improperly given that **EVERY OTHER BROWSER IS WORKING PERFECTLY**.

Comment: you already compared requests. said that they are the same, except of User-agent string. The only way the problem could come from - session assigned to browser, remove session cookie. Also, based on URL - it is a part of MVC, so the error can be created not in FAQ.php, but in any other file connected to it. check server's logs.

Answer (score 2):

Not if that explains the error code 500, but the JS code looks broken for me. Instead of the closing ; you are missing there one more pair of parenthesis: })
And check your server logs for the details about the error. If the server says 500, that means something happened on the server side and it is logged.

Comment: Good eye. I'm forever wresting with the 'code editor' in here. Fixed up now.

Answer (score 1):

For the N-th time I'm repeating that the problem is in your script or server config. And I found it - your server reacts weirdly on the Referer field of the http request.

IE submits URL in Referer with hash in it and your script (or MVC or server config/security settings) does not like it. I made a simulation of the POST request and 500 error happens due to **#!/Services** (or any other hashtag) in Referer field of the request:

```
Referer: http://adr.visia.ca/#!/Services
```

Other browsers do not send hash in request, but this is not a problem of some specific browser (IE) - this is the problem of your server or server-side scripts!

Comment: There's nothing in my code that 'does not like' the #! in the url. The reason you got this from both urls is because they both load the same 'Interior.php' template.

Comment: @AJB again, I do not want to discuss this. If you do not trust me, when I explained and showed everything - this your own problem. **I told you that I simulated request WITHOUT ANY BROWSER** and I've got 500 error when hashtag is present and normal 200 response without it. Why this happens on your server - I can not tell without seeing config and scripts. Even setup of `mod_security` can do it, I think. Stay with your opinion, believe nobody. Why do you ask question at SO in that case??

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is CORS.

IE8/9 will return a 500 if the CORS header isn't present and bail out on the request.  To repeat, **IE is giving the 500 error and not your server** -- I know this doesn't make sense, but IE doesn't make sense either.

If you are like me, you have something in your htaccess or other server config to return the CORS header based on the referrer.

**IE8/9 does not use normal AJAX, they use XDomainRequest and those requests do not pass over a referrer.**

You need to find a way to set that header in order for things to work.